# Is there a function for creating a index based presence of a value in columns?

Tags: r

```
 CARDID BSTN BSTN2 BSTN3 BSTN4 BSTN5
 5786  150     0     0     0     0
 9737  150     0     0     0     0
45924  150   151   154     0     0
66405  150     0     0     0     0
91720  150     0     0  4233     0
96172  150     0     0     0  3000
```

The result I want is a new column added to this data frame with the number of values present in max BSTN(n).

so for the first row the result of the new column would be
1 since only BSTN 1 has a value.

for the fifth row the result would be 4 since BSTN 4 has existing value.  with the same logic the results of the new columns would look like below.

```
 CARDID BSTN BSTN2 BSTN3 BSTN4 BSTN5 NTF
 5786  150     0     0     0     0    1
 9737  150     0     0     0     0    1
45924  150   151   154     0     0    3
66405  150     0     0     0     0    1
91720  150     0     0  4233     0    4
96172  150     0     0     0  3000    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col` with `ties.method = "last"` to get the column number of last non-zero value.

```
df$NTF <- max.col(df[-1] != 0, ties.method = "last")
df

#  CARDID BSTN BSTN2 BSTN3 BSTN4 BSTN5 NTF
#1   5786  150     0     0     0     0   1
#2   9737  150     0     0     0     0   1
#3  45924  150   151   154     0     0   3
#4  66405  150     0     0     0     0   1
#5  91720  150     0     0  4233     0   4
#6  96172  150     0     0     0  3000   5
```

If you have other columns before and/or after `"BSTN"` columns, we can use `grep` to select only the columns in which we are interested.

```
cols <- grep('^BSTN', names(df))
df$NTF <- max.col(df[cols] != 0, ties.method = "last")
```

---

We can also use `apply` row-wise :

```
apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) max(which(x != 0)))
#[1] 1 1 3 1 4 5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(CARDID = c(5786L, 9737L, 45924L, 66405L, 91720L, 
96172L), BSTN = c(150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L), BSTN2 = c(0L, 
0L, 151L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BSTN3 = c(0L, 0L, 154L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BSTN4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4233L, 0L), BSTN5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3000L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks!! But  actually I have more columns  otherwise than BSTNs in my actual data set . How would I edit this function to only count the max.cols with BSTNs.

Comment: @YunHyunsoo Yes, I have included that in the answer. Find the columns using `grep`, `cols <- grep('^BSTN', names(df))` and then use `max.col` on those columns `df$NTF <- max.col(df[cols] != 0, ties.method = "last")`

Comment: Im a bit understanding grep and the regular expressions.  The problem I encounterd is that I have  a column name called "BSTN.r " which I dont want to be considered . is there a way I write grep in this situation? I tried  added a '.' to write  '^BSTN.' , but in this case it seems to eliminate BSTN because there isn't a number labeled (like BSTN2 or BSTN3)

Comment: If you want to select columns with "BSTN" followed by a number, you could use `cols <- grep('^BSTN\\d+', names(df))`

Comment: Thank you! but cols <- grep('^BSTN\\d+', names(df))  does not seem to include BSTN. ... What if I would like to include BSTN BSTN1, .. BSTN5 and exclude BSTN.r  sorry to bother you so much

Comment: Do you have "." in column names or not, I am confused. Well, if "BSTN.r" is the only column which is coming out incorrectly, you can remove it. `cols <- setdiff(grep('^BSTN', names(df), value = TRUE), 'BSTN.r')`